# How to custom output with markdown-it [node-js]

Tags: javascript

My input with data

```
const data = `#test    : [separator]#`
```

target output

```
<div> <div>test : </div> <div>[separator]</div> </div>
```

How to make it with markdown-it library javascript??

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, you need to pass it into their `render` function. That will then give you the HTML.

If you want your `#test    : [separator]#` to look exactly like your example HTML output, you need to fix your string so the markdown will actually translate to that. Markdown has no concept of what a `div` is.

```js
const data = `test    : [separator]`;
const element = document.getElementById('test');

const md = window.markdownit();
const result = md.render(data);
console.log('MD Result', result);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/12.0.4/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think that gives me an answer

Comment: It does. It shows you how to use it. What you want is invalid because markdown doesn't translate like that. For example `# test` in markdown is `<h1> Test </h1>`.  Are you sure this library is the solution to your problem?

Comment: for that why I ask here, but it seems your answer does not match what I want

Comment: It does, actually. You should read more about HTML and Markdown and the difference between the two.